# AppEngine standard — cannot set <min-instances> to 0 in appengine-web.xml

Tags: java, google-app-engine

With the new [rollout](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2018/05/Increase-performance-while-reducing-costs-with-the-new-App-Engine-scheduler.html) of the AppEngine's autoscaler, the new [configuration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#scaling_elements_automatic_scaling) options like `min-instances` and `max-instances` were added for the automatic-scaling configuration saying that it is possible to, e.g. set number of minimum instances to 0 to reduce costs:

> `<min-instances>`
>
> Optional. The minimum number of instances for App
>   Engine to create for this module version. These instances serve
>   traffic when requests arrive, and continue to serve traffic even when
>   additional instances are started up as required to handle traffic.
>
> Specify a value from 0 to 1000. You can set the parameter to the value
>   0 to allow scaling to 0 instances to lower costs when no requests are
>   being served. Note that you are charged for the number of instances
>   specified whether they are receiving traffic or not.

But, regarding the `xsd` schema supplied with the AppEngine cloud SDK only `positive-integer` could be set within `min-instances` or `max-instances` tags:

```
<xs:complexType name="automatic-scaling-type">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="min-pending-latency" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="max-pending-latency" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="min-idle-instances" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="max-idle-instances" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:positiveInteger" name="min-instances" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:positiveInteger" name="max-instances" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:double" name="target-cpu-utilization" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:double" name="target-throughput-utilization" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="max-concurrent-requests" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:positiveInteger" name="min-num-instances" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:positiveInteger" name="max-num-instances" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:positiveInteger" name="cool-down-period-sec" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="ns:cpu-utilization-type" name="cpu-utilization" minOccurs="0" xmlns:ns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:positiveInteger" name="target-network-sent-bytes-per-sec" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:positiveInteger" name="target-network-sent-packets-per-sec" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:positiveInteger" name="target-network-received-bytes-per-sec" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:positiveInteger" name="target-network-received-packets-per-sec" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:positiveInteger" name="target-disk-write-bytes-per-sec" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:positiveInteger" name="target-disk-write-ops-per-sec" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:positiveInteger" name="target-disk-read-bytes-per-sec" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:positiveInteger" name="target-disk-read-ops-per-sec" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:positiveInteger" name="target-request-count-per-sec" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:positiveInteger" name="target-concurrent-requests" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="ns:flex-custom-metrics-array" name="custom-metrics" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>
```

I do agree that setting it to positive integer makes sense for `max-instances` but what about `min-instances`? Is it a bug or misprint in the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80273043) in the Java AppEngine SDK that is resolved now with the new SDK version: [1.9.64](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/release-notes#may_31_2018).